# Поиск элемента по кириллическим символам в Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, кириллица

Столкнулся с проблемой поиска элемента.
Мне необходимо кликнуть кнопку, название которой написано на кириллице.

```
.get("driver.find_element_by_link_text("кнопка").click()")
```

Сценарий отваливается на этапе запуска с ошибкой:

> "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Самое странное, что у коллеги работает. Хотелось бы решить проблему именно запуском кейса с кириллицей. `coding utf-8` в начале сценария не помогает

з.ы. os opensuse leap42.3

Answer (score 2):

Invalid syntax это не про кириллицу. У вас кавычка перед словом "кнопка" на самом деле не открывает кавычки для слова "кнопка", а закрывает первую кавычку (перед "driver).

Используйте кавычки разного типа, например, так:

```
.get("driver.find_element_by_link_text('кнопка').click()")
```

или наоборот:

```
.get('driver.find_element_by_link_text("кнопка").click()')
```

Comment: блин. И правда. Пропустил. Заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь! :)

Answer (score 0):

Сценарий отваливается по причине того что вы используете неверный синтаксис. Ваше выражение должно выглядеть так:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("кнопка").click()
```

get отвечает за переход по ссылке, и ожидает получить строку формата 'https://yoursite.com'